# Specify point release on d-i preseeding

Tags: 12.04, versions, release-management, preseed

Can I specify point release, say, "12.04.3" instead of "precise" in preseed.cfg for kickstart installation?

When I specify precise in d-i mirror/suite like

```
d-i mirror/suite precise
```

it will install "12.04.4" which I'm not willing to.

Comment: Can you tell why don't you want 12.04.4?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I need it to build completely same environment as a customer has, inside closed network. I will use it to reproduce the procedure and problems the customer faced. The application is outside of Ubuntu but there are some packages dependencies. I found building 12.04.3 is quicker way rather than downgrading, surveying dependency, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that is not possible.

The preseed file will always pick up the current version so this will always be the latest point release.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I searched for the way but came to the same answer. I will build a 12.04.3 local repository to achieve my purpose. Thank you again.